# How to Make text appear and disappear on image after tapping.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a code,

Suppose there is an image on mobile. And if we tap on image text appears, if we tap on the image again, the text disappears. Can someone give me the simple html, css and javascript code for this functionality? The image should be resposive.

please help.

Comment: Sorry, no. SO is for helping you debug issues with code that ***you*** have written. No one here is going to write code for you. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided, here is a solution that allows the visibility of a **div** to be toggled when the **container** is clicked using **JavaScript**:

```
 <style>
    /* Container holding the image and the text */
    .container {
        position: relative;
    }

    /* Bottom right text */
    .text-block {
        position: absolute;
        width: 70%;
        height: 70%;
        top: 20px;
        left: 20px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }

    p {opacity: 1;}

    #clickToShow{display:none;} /* to hide by default */
</style>

<script>
    //now the function to toggle visibility
    function clickToShow() {
        var div = document.getElementById("clickToShow");
        div.style.display = div.style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";
    }
</script>
<!-- notice onclick="clickToShow()" this is how you call JS method-->
<div class="container" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="clickToShow();">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" alt="Norway" style="width:100%; height: 70%;">
    <div class="text-block" id="clickToShow"> 
        <h4>Nature</h4>
        <p>What a beautiful sunrise!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle showing it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/3e8pnLd4/8/